# Let $p \ge 5$ be prime. Prove $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{24}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p \ge 5$ be prime. Prove $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {24}$. I'm having some trouble drawing anything useful from $p$ being prime. What can we say about p being prime that will help prove the statement?